# How to access global variables, declared in one class, during another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm making my first mobile phone and desktop application with Python and Kivy.
The purpose of the app is to reduce time spent on planning calculations for training flights.

So, I have multiple classes, each for a different 'screen' on the app. On each screen, different inputs are made along the way. At the end, there is a 'results screen' which shall print out the calculations made during that section.

For example, the wind direction/velocity and runway direction is entered on one screen, and the results page prints out the headwind and crosswind components.

However, since this results screen is a different class to the screen on which the wind is entered, I cannot add the str(var) to the kivy label, as not defined.

This is also my first time using Kivy and Classes etc. Any advice is really appreciated. My python knowledge is not too great.

Many thanks!

I tried to define a function outside of all the classes. I.e.

```
class Takeoff_3Window(Screen):

    def wind_Velocity1(self):
        global var
        ... code ...

wind_Result = Takeoff_3Window(Screen)
wind_Result.wind_Velocity()
```

and then trying making wind_Result global, to be able to call it in another class.

However, the wind_Velocity1(self) is called when a button is pressed.

```
class Takeoff_3Window(Screen):

    rwy1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    wd1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    wv1 = ObjectProperty(None)

    ...
    functions to input runway number, wind direction and wind velocity

    another function, called advance_TO3() checks all the other inputs were valid
    ...

    def TO_4Btn(self, math):
        global HWC1, XWC1
        self.advance_TO3()
        if advance_TO3 is True:
            HWC1 = round((WV1 * math.cos(math.radians(abs(RWY1 - WD1)))), 1)
            XWC1 = round((WV1 * math.sin(math.radians(abs(RWY1 - WD1)))), 1)
            sm.current = "SurfaceDetails"
        else:
            pass

...
further classes (screens) take other input data from the user, similar to above
...

class Takeoff_ResultWindow(Screen):

    tor_tom = ObjectProperty(None)
    tor_cog = ObjectProperty(None)
    tor_elev = ObjectProperty(None)
    tor_wv = ObjectProperty(None)
    tor_qnh = ObjectProperty(None)
    tor_hwc = ObjectProperty(None)
    tor_palt = ObjectProperty(None)
    tor_xwc = ObjectProperty(None)
    tor_temp = ObjectProperty(None)
    tor_rwy = ObjectProperty(None)

    def TOR_Page1(self):
        pressureAlt1 = 0
        self.tor_tom.text = "TOM: " + str(TOM)
        self.tor_cog.text = "Centre of Gravity: " + str((TO_Moment*1000)/TOM)
        self.tor_elev.text = "Elevation: " + str(Elevation1)
        self.tor_wv.text = "Wind Velocity: " + str(WV1)
        self.tor_qnh.text = "QNH: " + str(QNH_1)
        self.tor_hwc.text = "Wind (HWC): " + str(HWC1)
        self.tor_palt.text = "Pressure Alt.: " + str(pressureAlt1)
        self.tor_xwc.text = "Wind (XWC): " + str(XWC1)
        self.tor_temp.text = "Temperature: " + str(Temp1)
        self.tor_rwy.text = "Runway: " + str(RWY1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need a global variable?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Using globals is not the way to make two instances communicated. Instead you should have either one of the instances have a reference to the other and let it pass the value, or have a third class that has references to both and handles the passing of data. Note that Python does **not** have real global variables. "Global" variables are actually only module-level variables. If your classes are defined in different files you cannot access the globals of the other module, you'll have to import the module and access those as attributes of the module object.

Comment: I was about to say something down the lines of "you usually don't need to use global variables" but looks like Alzetta beat me to it

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Thank you all for your responses. As I say, very new to this! My assumption was that "global" made the variable accessible throughout the entire file. All of the classes are within the same .py file. So, how would I use the technique of a third class passing the data? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with your global variables, so I am taking a shot in the dark here.

I would recommend **not** using global variables.  Instead I would declare the variables in your class `__init__`, then you can *inherit* those variables in your other classes.

For example:

```
ClassA:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = 'some_value'
        self.foobar = 'abcd'

# class initialization
classA = ClassA('some_other_value') #this will set self.foo = 'some_other_value'
```

After initializing your class, you can access `self.<variable>` as a property of the class:

```
classA = ClassA('some_other_value')
print(classA.foo) # prints some_other_value
```

Now, in your ClassB, you can *inherit* all the properties of ClassA:

```
ClassB(Screen, ClassA):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        ClassA.__init__(self, foo)
        self.bar = 'some_new_value' #you can override properties from ClassA like this

classB = ClassB('some_other_value')

print(classB.foo) # prints 'some_other_value'
print(classB.bar) # prints 'some_new_value'
print(classB.foobar) #prints 'abcd'
```

In your exact situation, I would create the `HWC1` and XWC1` variables inside of your class init, then you can access them in all of your other classes via inheritance:

```
class Takeoff_3Window(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        rwy1 = ObjectProperty(None)
        wd1 = ObjectProperty(None)
        wv1 = ObjectProperty(None)
        self.HWC1 = round((WV1 * math.cos(math.radians(abs(RWY1 - WD1)))), 1)
        self.XWC1 = round((WV1 * math.sin(math.radians(abs(RWY1 - WD1)))), 1)
```

Now in your other class:

```
class Takeoff_ResultWindow(Screen, Takeoff_3Window):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.HWC1)
        print(self.XWC1)
```

Comment: I really am appreciating the help! So I thought that by declaring a variable as "global", you could access it anywhere in the entire code. So, even if I declared a variable in a class, as long as I put global, I could call that variable with its value in another class. Therefore, in one class (as every page in my app has its own class), the Headwind is calculated. I labelled it global so that in the results page (another class), I could just simply call the variable headwind so I can print it. Is your explanation the best way to tackle it?

Comment: The update definitely helped my understanding! Afraid the last issue I ran into was a MRO issue, as Takeoff_ResultWindow was inheriting from both Screen and Takeoff_3Window, yet Takeoff_3Window already inherits from Screen. I then removd the Screen element, but now when I reach the results page in my app, it now superimposes both pages into each other (the labels from the kivy file etc). I've googled results to overcome but no luck yet. Sorry to keep bothering you!

Comment: @MattS sorry I fell asleep.  Did you figure it out?